# How to get class name in code as static string property

Tags: c#, class, static, gettype

I want to get something like this:

```
public class myclass()
{
    public static string ClassName { get { return "myclass"; } }        
}
```

Is there a general way to substitude the string "myclass" in the above code example with the name of the owning class? 
I know that we can do this in non static way:

```
    public string ClassName { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
```

But in static?

Comment: you can just call getType on the static object, not sure why you'd want to expose your classes name to the public though

Comment: @Sayse or even have it "static". I mean its as static as it is compiled, isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test
{
       public static string ClassName
       {
          get
          {
             return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
          }
       } 
}
```

Comment: This won't work in case any class derives from `Test` and ask for class name. It will always return `Test` instead of concrete class.